# Python - Корректный вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, input

*Подскажите, где запутался?
Прога должна корректно выводить  ("n", программист /а /ов)*

```
n = int(input())
0 <= n <= 1000
if n % 10 == 2 or n % 10 == 3 or n % 10 == 4 and n % 10 == 1:
    print(n, "программиста")
elif (n % 10) // 10 and n == 2 or n == 3 or n == 4:
    print(n, "программиста")
if n % 10 == 1 and n % 100 == 1:
    print(n, "программист")
if n % 10 == 5 or n % 10 == 6 or n % 10 == 7 or n % 10 == 8 or n % 10== 9 or n % 10 == 0:
    print(n, "программистов")
elif n % 100 == 1 and n % 100 == 2 and n % 100 == 3 and n % 100 == 4:
    print(n, "программистов")
```

Comment: 12 программиста?

Comment: Непонятно по какому принципу вы вдруг вместо or пишете and местами. Ну и в целом кажется, что вы не очень понимаете, что проверяете.

Comment: @Leonid а вот последняя проверка наверняка для этого и была задумана, только куда-то десятка подевалась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

еще эту задачу можно решить без использования if, как-то так:

```
n = input()
d = {
    n[-1] == '1': 'программист',
    n[-1] in ['2','3','4']: 'программиста',    
    int(n[-2:]) in range(11,20): 'программистов',    
}.get(True,'программистов')
print(n, d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вначале отсекаем сотни, так как по правилам русского языка 1 или 101, или 801 - окончания те же: `n = n%100`

В целом для ***1, 21, 31, ...91*** - "*программист*".

Для ***2,3,4,22,23,24,...92,93,94*** - "*программиста*".

Для ***0,5,6,7,8,9,10,11-19,20,25,26,27,28,29,...99,100*** - "*программистов*".

То есть, кроме **11-19** все зависит от последней цифры, поэтому создаю базовую строку "программист", а дальше проверяю условия, начиная с блока с участием исключительного случая (11-19), объединяя условия по вариации окончания.

`(5 <= n%10 <= 9) or (11 <= n <= 19) or n%10 == 0` => "программистов" (окончание "ов")

`n%10 == 1` => "программист" (без окончания)

`2 <= n%10 <= 4` => "программиста" (окончание "а") - оставшийся вариант, поэтому условие не прописываю - только `else`

После выхода из блока проверок по уловиям, окончание добавляется к базовой строке конкатенацией.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
    let n = e.target.value%100;
    let add = '';
    if((n%10 >= 5 && n%10 <= 9) || (n >= 11 && n <= 19) || n%10 === 0){
        add = 'ов';
    } else if(n%10 === 1){
        add = '';
    } else {
        add = 'a';
    }
    document.querySelector('p').textContent = 'программист' + add;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000">
<p></p>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Need_Code если язык не важен  (хотя с чего бы вдруг), то нужно об этом указывать в вопросе

Comment: @Эникейщик я думал по меткам можно понять, но учту на будущее. Спасибо!

Comment: @Need_Code Что можно прогнать по меткам? в метках написано питон, в вопросе у вас питон. А в ответе вдруг яваскрипт...

Comment: @Эникейщик как и писал выше, учту. Исправил. Спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: @Эникейщик, во-первых, есть метка `алгоритм`, а она подразумевает, что сама логика решения вопроса - существенная часть вопроса. И инструкции на JS достаточно читаемы, но согласен - не для всех, а потому добавил пояснения. Во-вторых, JS - единственный способ запустить работу алгоритма прямо здесь и проверить результат - протестировать логику. В-третьих, ВСЁ, ЧТО МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ НАПИСАНО НА JAVASCRIPT - БУДЕТ РАНО ИЛИ ПОЗДНО НАПИСАНО НА JAVASCRIPT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Решил как-то так) Знаю, что не ахти, можно и короче, но я учусь)

```
n = int(input())
if n % 10 == 0:
    print(n,"программистов")
elif n % 10 == 1 and (n // 10) % 10 == 1:
    print(n,"программистов")
elif (n // 10) % 10 == 1:
    print(n,"программистов")
elif n % 10 == 5 or n % 10 == 6 or n % 10 == 7 or n % 10 == 8 or n % 10 == 9:
    print(n,"программистов")    
elif n == 5 or n == 6 or n == 7 or n == 8 or n == 9:
    print(n,"программистов")
elif n % 10 == 1 and (n // 10) % 10 != 1:
    print(n,"программист")
elif (n // 10) % 10 != 1 and n % 10 == 2 or n % 10 == 3 or n % 10 == 4:
    print(n,"программиста")
```

Comment: Условие (n // 10) % 10 == 1 повторяется два раза.