# Как изменить код, чтобы работали склонения? vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть vue код:

```
getTitle(number) {
 return `${number} Деталь${number > 1 ? 'Деталей' : ''}`;
}
```

Вызывается в шаблоне: `{{ getTitle(2) }}`

Как нужно передавать, если число деталей получается через api, в шаблоне выводится `{{ item.in_stock }}`

Скрипт срабатывает, но только на число 1. (если, скажем, число 251 - то пишет деталей)
Хотел сделать через includes, но не удалось.

Вопрос заключается: Как правильно передавать из шаблона `{{ item.in_stock }}`и как улучшить код,  чтобы при 251 выводилось слово "деталь"?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это не полный список склонений: 1 - деталь, 2|3|4 - детали,  5|6|7|8|9|х0 - деталей. Помимо это 11 - деталей, а 21 - деталь. Скорее всего библиотека нужна, ну или как минимум объект с диапазонами числовых значений и соответствующими склонениями слов.

Comment: @XelaNimed То есть, без библиотеки это будет геморрой?:\

Comment: Скорее всего это будет велосипед с квадратными колёсами. Это распостранённая задача и скорее всего для этого есть готовое решение и наверное даже не одно.

Comment: Доп. зависимости совсем не обязательны. Если в вoпросе появится работоспособный сниппет - покажу как надо решать такие задачи с Vue.

Comment: Буквально только что на metanit добавили [раздел по локализации](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/18.4.php) в стандарте ES2021. Посмотрите в эту сторону, ну как минимум, попробуйте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если очень хочется через тернарный оператор, то можно:

```
n%100<11||n%100>19?n%10!=1?n%10>1&&n%10<5?'и':'ей':'ь':'ей'
```

В коде добавил скобки для большей читаемости.

```js
function getTitle(n) {
return `${n} детал${(n%100<11 || n%100>19)?((n%10!=1)?((n%10>1 && n%10<5)?'и':'ей'):'ь'):'ей'}`;
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',changeTitle);

function changeTitle(e){
    document.querySelector('h1').textContent = getTitle(+e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0">
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1327658/342397 - только что был такой же вопрос, пояснения по логике там, не буду повторяться.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, этот ответ увы не в тему вопроса (Vue), т.е. отвечает на другой вопрос - не тот что задан тут. Правильное решение с этой библиотекой выглядит совсем иначе (но ТС ленится читать оф.доку и/или дооформлять вопрос для получения правильных ответов... это как минимум одна из причин их отсутствия).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, бездействие ТСа этому мешает, о чем вполне ясно и однозначно написано в комменте выше. Могу и болдом :) **в вопросе отсутствуют данные необходимые для правильного ответа**. То что вредный в контексте Vue ответ был принят, лишь еще больше отвращает от этого вопроса (т.к. он популяризует плохие практики, а именно прямую работу с DOM при использовании реактивной библиотеки). Разумнее этот вопрос проигнорировать в пользу будущих: о том же самом, но более качественных == полезных сообществу.

Comment: Всем заинтересованным в получении правильного ответа, предлагаю [задать новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (о той же задаче "[vue] склонение словосочетаний с числительными"), но уже [качественный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - если кинете хайлайт, помогу и ответом приложив все свои знания, и в продвижении качественного вопроса "каноничным".